# Quero mostrar um elemento após uma semana usando PHP

Tags: php

Acho que existe um códio usando a expressão if ao estilo `<?php if (mostrar depois de uma semana()): ?> Elemento aqui <?php endif; ?>`

Procurei por tudo que é canto e nada. Ainda sou leigo nisso, mas aprendo rápido.

Comment: Poste seu codigo para podermos ajudar

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito vaga. Edite com mais detalhes, código e imagens se achar necessário.

Comment: Postei uma solução genérica, mas convém nas próximas perguntas dar mais detalhes. Fundamental ler o [Tour], [Ask], [Help] e [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/70) para melhor aproveitamento do site.

Answer (score 4):

"Após uma semana" parte do princípio que você sabe de alguma
forma quando começou a contar essa semana.

### Data literal

Já tendo a data desejada, o código base é esse:

```
<?php
    if( date( 'Y-m-d' ) >= '2018-04-20' ) {
?>
    <p>Seu HTML aqui</p>
<?php
    }
?>
```

A função `date` usada desta forma retorna uma *string*, prática para
comparações literais (data digitada no código).

Importante neste contexto que a data seja sempre no formato ano-mes-dia,
pois se inverter a ordem, a lógica do `>=` perde o sentido.

### Data relativa (calculada)

Se for armazenar a data corrente, pode trabalhar com timestamps, para facilitar:

Código que recebe a data corrente:

```
$agora = time();
```

Calculando uma semana depois:

```
$umasemanadepois = $agora + ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 );
```

**Guarde esse valor em algum lugar, não pode por no código do `if` senão o tempo
de início vai ser reiniciado toda vez, nunca chegando a "semana depois".**

Aplicando no `if`:

```
<?php
    if( time() >= $umasemanadepois ) {
?>
    <p>Seu HTML aqui</p>
<?php
    }
?>
```

### Notas

- Use `gmdate()` se quiser ignorar o fuso horário local;
- no caso do `time` é o inverso, o `mktime` pode ser usado para fuso local;
- o `time()` retorna a data em segundos, por isto é necessário o cálculo de uma semana para ajustar:

  ```
  7 * 24 * 60 * 60`
  ```

  Sete dias × 24 horas × 60 minutos × 60 segundos